# Dynamic Class in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to build a simple class that when extended gives a class two functions, `save()` & `read()`. This class will serialize the subclass and store it in a .ser file. and also deserialize it and restore the state.

I am thinking of using a builder for initializing the subclass. With this, the class will always start with the previous state or make a new state if required.

```
Todo x = new Todo().Builder().className(Todo.class).build();
```

The `save()` function is working just fine.

```
    public void save(String fileName) {
        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName+".ser");
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);

            out.writeObject(this);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In the `Builder()` function where I am taking the `Todo.class` as a parameter 
I am using `Class<?> className` but now I am not able to figure out what I have to do.

Builder function I want to load the object of the class and return it. 
An in the read function I want to update the state of the class.

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectInputStream` creates and returns a full object, I don't know how you want to combine that with your builder idea. Here's a simple method to read an object of an arbitrary class from a file:

```
    public static <T> T read(String fileName, Class<T> klass) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Path filePath = Path.of(fileName);
        try (ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(filePath))) {
            return klass.cast(objectInputStream.readObject());
        }
    }
```

Comment: To return an Object do I have to know the Class name because I am trying to return a dynamic class.

Comment: You don't have to know the class name, the name of the class is included in the file. The example I included accepts `klass` parameter only to use `klass.cast()`. You could just as well use `(T) objectInputStream.readObject()` but that gives you an "unchecked operation" warning.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get the object back